# Storing files outside of ASP.net on server using ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file, storage

I've been reading on MSDN, stackoverflow, codeproject etc for the last couple of days and I can't seem to resolve this.

In PHP this was easy, make a directory assign permissions read/write files. Which was great because I could store above or outside of the front facing application.

I am using VS 2013 Professional with a webforms application with c# behind.

I want to be able to read/write GUID coded images to a specified directory, outside of asp.net as I don't want to keep track of the files in visual studio just verify their existence in the program.

I'd prefer to not store them inside the database as the amount of data will become costly as db storage is expensive vs. disk space.

I want the directory to be able to store images and display on command. I don't want any execution to be allowed in those directories.

The errors I get are access denied after creating the directories in WS-FTP with appropriate permissions inside the project area or unable to locate resource E:\blah\blah\UserData\LocImg. I also don't want to statically call out E:\blah\blah.....

If I create the directories in VS they don't "publish" and I'm concerned as I also don't want publishing to erase any existing data in the directories. If I create directories above wwwroot inside the project area using WS-FTP, they are removed during publishing.

My preferred directory structure is:
UserData
 |--UserImg
 |--LocImg

So this is what I have.

Web Config: Has

```
    <location path="UserData">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <!-- <deny users="*" /> -->
            <allow verbs="GET" users="*"/>
            <allow verbs="POST" users="*"/>
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="UserData/LocImg">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <!-- <deny users="*" /> -->
            <allow verbs="GET" users="*"/>
            <allow verbs="POST" users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="UserData/UserImg">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <!-- <deny users="*" /> -->
            <allow verbs="GET" users="*"/>
            <allow verbs="POST" users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Note that I originally has deny all set.

ASPX Page a simple drag and drop file selector.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

CodeBehind:

```
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            Boolean fileOK = false;
            String path = Server.MapPath("../UserData/LocImg/");
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                String fileExtension =
                        System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();
                String[] allowedExtensions = { ".gif", ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg" };
                for (int i = 0; i < allowedExtensions.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fileExtension == allowedExtensions[i])
                    {
                        fileOK = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (fileOK)
            {
                try
                {
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path
                            + FileUpload1.FileName);
                    Label1.Text = "File uploaded!";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "File could not be uploaded. :" + ex.Message.ToString().Trim();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Cannot accept files of this type.";
            }
        }
```

I have tried all sorts of variants of the file location short of E:\blah\blah.
I even tried http:\www. , ~/UserData/LocImg, ../UserData/LocImg and that didn't work either.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you control the server? If it's a managed service, you likely can't access files outside pre-defined areas.

Comment: Thanks Mason. I do not have control over the server. I can however access/read/write/create/edit/delete above wwwroot in WS-FTP ie  blah.com in blah.com/wwwroot/ That is where I would prefer to put files but if not, inside wwwroot is ok too but VS removes references to empty folders or folders it doesn't recognize.

Comment: So use your FTP to create the top level folder? Assign it permissions via the admin interface to your service. Then just point your web application at them?

Comment: Yes. This is what I've done in the past using PHP without problems. The issue seems to be that ASP doesn't recognize them. And if I point directly to them, I have to use explicit E:\blah\blah. Which would work... until something changed on the server side or if I move hosts or upgrade to dedicated server..... At this point I just want to be able to store the data and will figure out or change the coding if I move or the server gets reconfigured. Not the solution I was hoping for but seems as though this is my solution and where I am at, which is why I am putting this out for input.

Comment: Well in your configuration file, specify a base directory. Then in your application code, make all configuration relative to that base directory. Then if things change, you only have to update one location.

Comment: We do this with a virtual directory in IIS.  You can make any directory look like it is within the ASP.NET website, and the best part is that the virtual directory does not actually exist on the disk in your website structure, thus removing your ability to accidentally delete it when publishing code.

Comment: Thanks Mason. Went with the separated solution you proposed. Thanks again!